# How to create constent object for aws dynamodb in python?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to know how can check if the boto3 client object already instantiated or not. i have below code for creating the object for aws dynamodb

```
import boto3
def aws_dynamodb():
   return boto3.resource("dynamodb")


def get_db_con():
    dynamo_conn=aws_dynamodb()
    return dynamo_conn
```

Now the above 'get_db_con()' return the connection to the dynamodb. but i want to make sure that 'get_db_con' not creating the client object from the 'aws_dynamodb()' everytime when its been called.

for eg:

```
def aws_db_table(table):
   con=get_db_con()
   return con.table(table)

account_table=aws_db_table("my_ac_table")
audit_table=aws_db_table("audit_table")
```

so here whenever i call the 'aws_db_table', it should not create the client for 'aws_dynamodb()' for everytime.

so how i can check it if the aws_dynamodb() is already instantiated or not creating new client object. Because creating client object everytime is costly..

Note: I want to run the code in Lambda function

Please help us on this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually go with a low-tech solution with a global variable that looks something like this:

```py
import boto3

# Underscore-prefix to indicate this is something private
_TABLE_RESOURCE = None

def get_table_resource():
    global _TABLE_RESOURCE
    if _TABLE_RESOURCE is None:
        _TABLE_RESOURCE = boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("my_table")
    return _TABLE_RESOURCE

def handler(event, context):
    table = get_table_resource()
    # ...
```

Global variables are persisted across Lambda executions, that's why this works.

Another option would be to use the [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from functools, which uses memoization.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
import boto3

@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def get_table_resource():
    return boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("my_table")

def handler(event, context):
    table = get_table_resource()
    # ...
```

For those not familiar with memoization the first solution is probably easier to read + understand.
(Note: I wrote the code from memory, there may be bugs)

Comment: Thanks @Maurice.. the solution with gloabal varibale work as expected.. However i would like to know using global variable in python is good ? i asking from the above scenario..

Comment: Generally it's good practice to avoid global variables. In your specific case you want persistence outside the scope of your function and for that it's fine. If I'm working with experienced python developers I prefer solution #2, but it uses less well known parts of the standard library...

Comment: @Cloud_Hari Feel free to accept this answer if it solved your problem, that tells other users your problem is solved :-)